# Acceso a un dict por su "nombre"

Tags: python

En el fichero examples.py, tengo dos tipos de estructuras una de tipo *String* y la otra de tipo *dict*. Quiero guardar estas en una lista de tulpas [(rule1, def1)], recorriendo el fichero y guardando la coincidencia, pero no logro hacer que resulte desde un .py externo.
La razón de esto, a *examples* si le agregara información de los tipos mencionados y no quiero agregar esta manualmente. existe alguna forma de hacer esto?
mi objetivo es que en la lista existena un triupla en la cual se alamacena el (indice,reglas'indice',definicion'indice')

```
#examples.py
ids = 4
definition1="L = {0^n 1^2n / n >= 1}; Palabra minima: 011"
rules1={('q','0','R'):('q','00R'),('q','0','0'):('q','000'),('q','1','0'):('p','E'),('p','1','0'):('p','E'),('p','E','R'):('p','R'),}
```

```
import examples as ex

ids = ex.ids
lista = []

def get_rules():
    archivo = open("examples.py" ,"r")
    data = archivo.readlines()
    i = 0
    for line in data:
        a = f'rules{i}'
        for i in range(0,ids):
            if a in line:
                lista.append((i,ex.))
                i=+1
            
get_rules()
print(lista)
```

output deseado:

```
lista = [(0,rules0,definition0),(1,rules1,definition1),(2,rules2,definition2),(3,rules3,definition3)]
```

y al momento de acceder a lista[0][1] por ejemplo obtenga el diccionario completo. si hago la lista dentro del mismo examples.py, funciona ya que no tengo que generar la lista desde otro .py, pero me genera problemas para agregar mas reglas y definiciones, ya que, estas se agregan al final del archivo.

Comment: Podrías poner una muestra del archivo de entrada, *examples.py*

Comment: @aeportugal ahí adjunte

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No está muy claro la pregunta. Esta respuesta supone que el objetivo es crear una lista con los contenidos de las variables mencionadas. Como es una solución corta, la pondre completa:

```
import examples as ex

lista = []
for indice in range(ex.ids):
    rules = getattr(ex, f"rules{indice}")
    defs = getattr(ex, f"definition{indice}")
    lista.append((indice, rules, defs))
```

**Análisis**

Al hacer `import examples as ex`, Python lee y ejecuta todo el código contenido en `examples.py`, que en este caso es

```
#examples.py
ids = 2
definition0="L = {0^n 1^2n / n >= 1}; Palabra minima: 011"
rules0={('q','0','R'):('q','00R'),('q','0','0'):('q','000'),('q','1','0'):('p','E'),('p','1','0'):('p','E'),('p','E','R'):('p','R'),}
definition1="L = {0^n 1^2n / n >= 1}; Palabra minima: 011"
rules1={('q','0','R'):('q','00R'),('q','0','0'):('q','000'),('q','1','0'):('p','E'),('p','1','0'):('p','E'),('p','E','R'):('p','R'),}
definition1="L = {0^n 1^2n / n >= 1}; Palabra minima: 011"
rules1={('q','0','R'):('q','00R'),('q','0','0'):('q','000'),('q','1','0'):('p','E'),('p','1','0'):('p','E'),('p','E','R'):('p','R'),}
```

Luego de leerlo y ejecutarlo, quedan definadas las variables `ids, rules1, definition1, rules2, definition2` y accesibles usando la convención `modulo.variable`.

Por ejemplo, `ex.ids` me da el número de reglas/definiciones definidas, con lo que puedo iterar preguntando por el valor asociado a la variable de ese nombre:

```
for indice in range(ex.ids):
    rules = getattr(ex, f"rules{indice}")
```

La función `getattr()` requiere un objeto (en este caso el módulo ya cargado) y un nombre (que construimos usando un f-string).

El valor retornado por `getattr()` es un **objeto Python**. En este caso, retorna un string y un diccionario. O sea, no es necesario interpretar el resultado para reconstruir el objeto deseado.

Teniendo los objetos recuperados, los agregamos a la lista final como una 3-tupla:

```
lista.append((indice, rules, defs))
```

Cada elemento de la lista contiene una tupla con reglas y definiciones.

#### Demo

*examples.py*

```
#examples.py
ids = 2
definition0="L = {0^n 1^2n / n >= 1}; Palabra minima: 011"
rules0={('q','0','R'):('q','00R'),('q','0','0'):('q','000'),('q','1','0'):('p','E'),('p','1','0'):('p','E'),('p','E','R'):('p','R'),}
definition1="L = {0^n 1^2n / n >= 1}; Palabra minima: 011"
rules1={('q','0','R'):('q','00R'),('q','0','0'):('q','000'),('q','1','0'):('p','E'),('p','1','0'):('p','E'),('p','E','R'):('p','R'),}
definition1="L = {0^n 1^2n / n >= 1}; Palabra minima: 011"
rules1={('q','0','R'):('q','00R'),('q','0','0'):('q','000'),('q','1','0'):('p','E'),('p','1','0'):('p','E'),('p','E','R'):('p','R'),}
```

*Código*

```
import examples as ex

lista = []
for indice in range(ex.ids):
    rules = getattr(ex, f"rules{indice}")
    defs = getattr(ex, f"definition{indice}")
    lista.append((indice, rules, defs))

for tupla in lista:
    id = tupla[0]
    rules = tupla[1]
    defs = tupla[2]
    print(f"Elemento {id}:")
    print(f"  rule{id} ({type(rules)}): {rules}")
    print(f"  definition{id} ({type(defs)}): {defs}")
```

produce:

```
Elemento 0:
  rule0 (<class 'dict'>): {('q', '0', 'R'): ('q', '00R'), ('q', '0', '0'): ('q', '000'), ('q', '1', '0'): ('p', 'E'), ('p', '1', '0'): ('p', 'E'), ('p', 'E', 'R'): ('p', 'R')}
  definition0 (<class 'str'>): L = {0^n 1^2n / n >= 1}; Palabra minima: 011
Elemento 1:
  rule1 (<class 'dict'>): {('q', '0', 'R'): ('q', '00R'), ('q', '0', '0'): ('q', '000'), ('q', '1', '0'): ('p', 'E'), ('p', '1', '0'): ('p', 'E'), ('p', 'E', 'R'): ('p', 'R')}
  definition1 (<class 'str'>): L = {0^n 1^2n / n >= 1}; Palabra minima: 011

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Wow, interpretaste muy bien mi pregunta, no sabía la existencia de getattr() muchísimas gracias!!